# React Native deep linking is not working url schama

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Deep Linking not working in my react native app(Android) when I clicked link from browser. It's working from ADB.
React Native deep linking is not working url schama
, Digital Asset Links JSON file hosted website but site link open not redirect the app ?

AndroidManifest.xml:

`<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />         <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->         <data android:scheme="https"               android:host="www.mycollegestudy.in" />     </intent-filter>`

React Native deep linking is not working please help me

Comment: I already configured this in my app and it wasn't easy... Can you add the code used in the browser (link to the app)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.